# Problems Using OpenSSL in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, openssl

I noticed some problems between installing OpenSSL on Windows XP Professional and Windows 7 Professional. For both OSs, I downloaded the `Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0d` and `Visual C++ 2008` Redistributables binaries from the Shining Light Productions website.  Both installed with no problems on both machines. However, on the Windows 7 machine, I encountered the following problems using the OpenSSL exe and API:

- From the MS-DOS command prompt, I tried to create a root CA with

  ```
  openssl x509 -req -in rootreq.pem -sha1  -extensions v3_ca 
    -signkey rootkey.pem -out rootcert.pem
  ```

but was given the following error `unable to write random state`.  Windows XP worked fine.

- I compiled a simple SSL web server using the OpenSSL API, but when I try to connect using

> ```
> openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:16001
> ```

I get the following response

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
connect: No such file or directory
connect:errno=0
```

Once again, Windows XP returned a better response.  If you look at my attached code, it appears that the second BIO_do_accept never gets called.

Does anyone know what the problem may be ?  Are there extra steps that I need to take when installing on Windows 7?

FYI - I also tried installing the 64 bit binaries on Windows 7 as well, but I got the same results.  I really need  to get this up and running on my Windows 7 machine, so any help is appreciated.

```
///////////////////  Code ///////////////////////////////////

// Simple OpenSSL Webserver
// Compiler : MSVS 2010 Professional
// Language: C / C++

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BIO         *acc, *client;
    SSL         *ssl;
    SSL_CTX     *ctx;
    THREAD_TYPE tid;

    init_OpenSSL(  );
    seed_prng(  );

    ctx = setup_server_ctx(  );

    acc = BIO_new_accept(PORT);

    printf ("BIO_new_accept\n");

    if (!acc)
        int_error("Error creating server socket");

    if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
        int_error("Error binding server socket");

    printf ("BIO_do_accept\n");

    for (;;)
    {
        if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
            int_error("Error accepting connection");

        printf ("BIO_do_accept2\n");

        client = BIO_pop(acc);

        printf ("BIO_pop\n");

        if (!(ssl = SSL_new(ctx)))
            int_error("Error creating SSL context");

        printf ("SSL_new\n");

        SSL_set_bio(ssl, client, client);

        printf ("SSL_set_bio\n");

        THREAD_CREATE(tid, (void *)server_thread, ssl);
    }

    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    BIO_free(acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the first call to BIO_do_accept() causes an error?

Answer (score 2):

I have success using the MinGW-w64 platform to build my OpenSSL applications (both for x86 and x64 Windows), and I also had some issues with the Shining Light binaries.

It is quite easy to set up, there are some instructions and a sample application at http://www.blogcompiler.com/2011/12/21/openssl-for-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I discovered that the best way was to compile everything myself.  I found a good tutorial at the following site - http://www.askyb.com/windows/compiling-and-installing-openssl-for-32-bit-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer.  I discovered that the best way was to compile everything myself.  I found a good tutorial at the following site - http://www.askyb.com/windows/compiling-and-installing-openssl-for-32-bit-windows/

Answer (score 0):

when you click on command prompt right click and click run as administrator that should clear up your issue